# Struggling to Display a Fetch request on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, dom, fetch

I've been studying Front End web dev for a few weeks now and I've got most of the basics down I think (I'm coming from C++ programming so very similar, yet so different in ways) but something I'm struggling with is displaying Data from fetch requests on a page, for example, I have an example JSON page to fetch the following data:

```
{
"data": \[

    {

        "order": 0,

        "items": \[
{
"order": 1,
"name": " Red",
"imgSrc": "Picture1.jpg"
},
{
"order": 0,
"name": "Blue",
"imgSrc": "Picture2.jpg"
},
{
"order": 2,
"name": "Black",
"imgSrc": "picture3.jpg"
}
        \],

"default\_configuration": \[

    2,

    1,

    0

\]
}
```

What I am trying to to do is display this data on an HTML page as a table that can be ordered by the "Order" data (perhaps in a table or a grid on the page), but cannot work it out, I can fetch the data fine and it is appearing in the Browser console as intended, using the following fetch request:

```
fetch('URL').then(function (response) {
// The API call was successful!

return response.json();
}).then(function (data) {
// This is the JSON from our response

console.log(data);
}).catch(function (err) {
// There was an error

console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
```

any help and understanding is appreciated.

I've now added the following to the Fetch request and its showing as a Null error:

```
const ul = document.getElementById('layers');
const url = 'https://lab.pikcells.com/code-exercise/data.json'

fetch(url).then(function (response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    return response.json();
}).then(function (data) {
    // This is the JSON from our response
    console.log(data);
    let orders = data.layers;
    return orders.map(function(orders){
        let li = createNode('li'),
            img = createNode('img'),
            span = createNode('span');
        img.src = 'https://lab.pikcells.com/code-exercise/images/';
        span.innerHTML = '${orders.order.item} ${order.item.name}';
        append(li,img);
        append(li, span);
        append(ul,li);
    })
}).catch(function (err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});

function createNode(element) {
  return document.createElement(element); // Create the type of element you pass in the parameters
}

function append(parent, el) {
  return parent.appendChild(el); // Append the second parameter(element) to the first one
}
```

Originally this line

img.src = 'https://lab.pikcells.com/code-exercise/images/';

Had, orders.picture.medium like I read in an example, but there is no Medium criteria in the JSON file, so I thought that replacing it with the direct URL where the pictures are located may help?

Comment: When you say you want to display it, how exactly do you want to do it? In a table? As plain JSON? Update your question to include the desired way of displaying the data. This is not a JavaScript question but probably more of a HTML one.

Comment: To add content to a HTML page with javascript you can use dom manipulation. You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I am on to something here, I've edited the above to show something, still an error but like I said, its pulling the data in